# Common Lisp Memory Issues

Tags: clisp

I am using GNU Clisp to compute a very big matrix represented as a hash table of hash tables.  The ultimate hash values being stored are single floats.

The program seems to run out of memory after a while and I am thinking I need to

1. change the variable type somehow of the ultimate values so as to use less memory
2. have the operating system allocate more memory
3. somehow use virtual memory from the hard drive; or some combination thereof.

Any suggestions?  I did a lot of searches and could not find anything.

Comment: Your question would be improved by specifying your platform, CLISP version, its build options, &c You should start with `clisp -version` output.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [`short-float`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_short_.htm) - they are immediate on all platforms that CLISP supports.
2. Depending on your platform you might want to use the [`-m`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/clisp.html#opt-memsize) option to allocation more memory, but I don't think this make any difference on a modern platform - CLISP will allocate all it needs as it goes, up to the physical + swap.
3. virtual memory (swap) should be enabled using OS. Note that it is very slow compared to physical RAM, so it should be relied upon judiciously.